# SCORM Player in Craft

Tags: integration

Has anyone ever tried and/or succeeded at integrating a [SCORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharable_Content_Object_Reference_Model) player with Craft?

I'd like to "roll my own" [LMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system) in Craft because [Moodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moodle) is WAY overkill, but I need to be able to deliver SCORM content, as well as access and utilize the data provided by the SCORM files.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about specific integrations with Craft per se, but one way to achieve this fairly quickly is to integrate with SCORM Cloud's API. It is a SaaS offering that can be leveraged to add SCORM capability to just about any site, LMS, CMS, etc. Integrations with Moodle, WordPress, etc. already exist. See https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/

Comment: It's a good option, but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve paying ongoing service or licensing fees.

Comment: @PhilipJones - Did you find a solution to this? I’m in the same boat. I‘d like to host Articulate Ride scorm packages and don’t need all of the features of Moodle and platforms like that. I’d rather not pay a monthly fee but if I could get ScormCloud api working in Craft that would be more desirable than Moodle, etc. Thanks!